# Get pk from URL in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to access the `pk` from URL but getting the following error:

> get() got multiple values for argument 'pk'

URL:

```
            path('grn-barcodes/<int:pk>/', GrnBarcodes.as_view()),
```

Views.py

```
class GrnBarcodes(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self,pk):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        print("pk is", pk)
        .
        .
        .
        return Response("done")
```

How do I get it in the Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your get method like this.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       pk = self.kwargs['pk']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `request` parameter:

```
class GrnBarcodes(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, pk):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        print("pk is", pk)
        .
        .
        .
        return Response("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the url in this format,

```
path(r'grn-barcodes/(?P<pk>\d+)', GrnBarcodes.as_view())
```

Also, the view should have request parameter as HuLu ViCa stated

```
class GrnBarcodes(APIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def get(self, request, pk):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    print("pk is", pk)
    .
    .
    .
    return Response("done")
```